# Enable different SSID for 2.4 GHz / 5 GHz Wi-Fi on TP-Link AC1300 Router (EC230-G1)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, dual-band

**tl;dr** *I have TP-Link AC1300 Router (EC230-G1) and I have trouble providing different SSIDs for 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz Wi-Fi band, because I cannot locate corresponding setting for 5 GHz bands. Does this router support such functionality (different SSIDs for different Wi-Fi bands) at all?*

---

There's a clear separation between 2.4 GHz / 5 GHz Wi-Fi bands in other sections of TP-Link AC1300 Router (EC230-G1)'s configuration panel's:

[image]
[image]

But I can't find this for basic Wi-Fi settings:

[image]

How should I understand this situation?

1. Is the Wi-Fi band separation defined somewhere else in the configuration or am I forced to use the same SSID for both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz?
2. If latter then how can my clients (supporting both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz Wi-Fi) distinguish networks / know which frequency to use to connect to given SSID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That router makes a mesh network so that you need the same SSIDs for both bands.

I have a Ubiquiti network here and both 2.4 and 5 GHz bands share the same SSID.

> how can my clients ... know which frequency to use to connect to given
> SSID

The device will determine the correct band. I have one 5 GHz device here and a 2.4 GHz device next to it. There is never any mistake in picking the band.

Support Article.

[TP Link Mesh](https://www.tp-link.com/ca/support/faq/2595/)

> TP-Link Smart Connect allows the router to automatically assign
> connected devices to the Wi-Fi band that provides the fastest speed.
> By balancing the load and assigning devices to the most appropriate
> band, Smart Connect can reduce delays and interruptions.
>
> When Smart Connect enabled, the router’s 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks
> share the same SSID (network name) and password.  You can enjoy a
> seamless connection between 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks.